# RESTful web service in Racket

Tags: web-services, scheme, racket

Is there a way to host a list using a web service in scheme/racket

Comment: It's all just software, I'm sure there's a way to do whatever you want. What have you tried? How did it not work as you expected?

Comment: What does hosting a list mean?

Comment: @JayMcCarthy: Hosting a list means, on GET request, contents of list should be received in json/xml format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If in your question you meant a Scheme/Racket `list`: Sure, you could make a RESTful API such that `POST`, `GET`, `PUT`, `DELETE` verbs modified a `list`. I suppose that could be a lite way to try various RESTful ideas. If you want to do this for real I recommend ["RESTful Web Services"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529260).

See ["Systems Programming in Racket"](http://docs.racket-lang.org/more/index.html) for how to make a simple HTTP server in Racket from scratch. In step 4, the tutorial is ignoring the request header and assuming the verb is `GET`. However you could pay attention to the verb in the request header.

You may be able to build up a lite HTTP server that meets your needs, this way. Or, after trying this, you may decide the full server provided in Racket is more suitable for your needs, and better appreciate what it's doing for you. That is described in ["Web Applications in Racket"](http://docs.racket-lang.org/continue/index.html)

Comment: I meant PLTScheme/Racket. Anything will work. I just wanted to find out a way to host lists. Later, I found there are various APIs on PLTScheme which I can use. Thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the references. They were helpful.

Comment: Hi @hrishikeshp19, could you point in the direction of these API docs? I'm also looking to build a restful server with Racket, but I don't want to do everything from scratch.

Comment: @kristianlm: http://planet.plt-scheme.org/ here is link to package repo of PLTscheme. I think "spin" package may be useful.